# How can i set width of a input group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do i set width of input in this case  in bootstrap 3.0

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/6eBFz/

**code**

```
    <div class="submit">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control ">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Add </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i am looking at the bootstrap way and not custom css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap inputs take on the width of their container.

From the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)..

> "Inputs, selects, and textareas are 100% wide by default in Bootstrap.
>   To use the inline form, you'll have to set a width on the form
>   controls used within."

Comment: what do they mean by form controls

Answer (score 1):

CSS: `.set-width{ width: 50%; }`

HTML: `<div class="input-group set-width">`

You can add a set-width method (call it whatever you want) on any div and then manually size it in your CSS. I wouldn't recommend adding `style="width: 50%;"` to code because it makes it less readable and makes it much harder to edit later on. Plus with making a CSS class you can reuse it on several input fields (or anything else that you want to be set to that width really! Width can be set in pixels, or in em.

[Here is a helpful resource](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3470231) to understand CSS classes and ID's

Comment: i ment the bootstrap way

Comment: there isn't a boostrap way, the boostrap default for fields is set to 100% of the container, if you want something different you have to override that